# WCF REST and IIS Express 7.5 returns Request Error (400)

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-express, http-status-code-400

I am struck with the following issue on hosting WCF Rest based services in IIS.

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetEmployee/{userid}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    IEnumerable<Employee> GetPlans(string userid);
}
```

TestService.svc.cs:

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployee(string userid)
    {    
        return Employee
    }
}
```

when I use Cassini server, it works fine returnштп result in json format. Url is the following:

```
http://localhost:58764/TestService/TestService.svc/GetEmployee/2
```

but when I host that in IIS Express 7.5 at URL:

```
http://localhost/TestService/TestService.svc/GetEmployee/2)
```

it simply says:

> "Request Error
>
> The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service."

but URL at

```
http://localhost/TestService/TestService.svc/help
```

returns all the available methods without any issues.

Comment: Are you sure that the object Employee is serializable. At times serialization over cassini passes but fails when hosted on IIS. Also try enabling tracing on your service when hosted on IIS to get the exact reason on why your request is failing. Might be due to the size of the data being returned as well

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this issue.

Can you try reinstalling the .net framework?

- Open Visual Studio 2010 command prompt
- Type "aspnet_regiis -i" and press enter
- restart IIS
- Check if IIS is having WCF component installed. If it is not installed.
- Run below command and restart IIS
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation>Service
  ModelReg.exe -i

Try after that. Hope it should work, I had similar issue that was resolved after these steps.

Comment: Thanks Shailesh. I tried the steps but the issue still occured. after that I tried with SVCTraceViewer.exe and found the issue was because of Impersonation problem. finally I resolved it.